# How to terminate the session from the service side?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Suppose you have created a duplex service - for example using NetTcpBinding - and that is configured to create a new session for each new subscription by a new client as the [publish-subscribe pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752254.aspx): every time a new client connects, a new service instance is created. If a client wants to disconnect, it invokes the `Unsubscribe()` method is sufficient to end its session.

Suppose also that the service has a method to verify if the client is active - that is, the client must periodically invoke this method: if the service detects that a client is no longer active, it makes sense that the service decides to disconnect from the client. Similarly, the service may decide to terminate all sessions if the user decides to close the application that hosts it.

- How to terminate the session from the service side?
- How could the client (that is, the automatically generated proxy) detect that the service wants to disconnect or that is disconnecting? Does it throw an exception?

**UPDATE**

I read about the `ICommunicationObject` interface, the `CommunicationObject` class, the `IDisposable` interface, etc.., so I tried to use an `ICommunicationObject` related to the callback:

```
ICommunicationObject obj = (ICommunicationObject)callback;
obj.Close();
```

In this way, the session instance in cleanly destroyed (the destructor `Dispose()` method is called after calling the `Close()` method) and If the client try to send a request, then a `ProtocolException` is launched on it:

> This channel can no longer be used to send messages as the output
>   session was auto-closed due to a server-initiated shutdown. Either
>   disable auto-close by setting the
>   DispatchRuntime.AutomaticInputSessionShutdown to false, or consider
>   modifying the shutdown protocol with the remote server.

Similarly, using the code above but calling the `Abort()` method, the service instance is destroyed, and the `CommunicationObjectFaultedException` exception is thrown on the client:

> The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel,
>   cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

The behavior that I got is pretty much what I want, but I'm not sure if this is the exact way to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to close session dut to inactivity you may better make use of reliable session inactivity timeout http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.reliablesession.inactivitytimeout.aspx, here infrastructure will automatically close session for you.  Otherwise for manual approach you may try OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext.Close() or OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext.Abort()

Comment: So I could also store these `OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext` objects in a `static` shared list in order to invoke the desired `InstanceContext` from another thread. Is that correct?

Comment: If I invoke `Close` or `Abort` methods within the instance of the service, neither of the two work: they return without exception, but the connection is not closed (the destructor `Dispose` is not invoked) and the client is still able to communicate. I also read about the `ReleaseServiceInstance` method and, trying to invoke it, it throws this exception: _the communication object, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext, is in the Created state. Communication objects cannot be used for communication unless they are in the Opened state_.

Comment: Abort/Close on instance context must throws exception and fault client channel. Alternatively you can manually throw exception from server even that will fault the channel on client and force them to create new proxy

Comment: The above exception is launched in the service instance when I invoke the `ReleaseServiceInstance()` method.